# Генерация рандомной строки

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Меня интересует, как можно генерировать строку вида `sa32Asf7w1` с помощью библиотеки random в python.
Первые 4 символа - рандомный набор букв и цифр, с 6 по 10 то же самое. 5 символ - рандомная заглавная буква.

Comment: Используйте `random.choices`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

как вариант - сделайте словарь букв и цифр и выбирайте оттуда, а 5 символ выберите из отдельного словаря (где только большие буквы) или из того же словаря, только с границами, соответствующими большие буквы

**итоговый вариант:**

```
import random
import string

text = [random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits if i != 5 else string.ascii_uppercase) for i in range(10)]

print(''.join(text))
```

варианты:

```
import random

letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', '3']

text = [letters[random.randint(0, len(letters))] for _ in range(10)]
text[5] = letters[random.randint(0, 3)]

print(''.join(text))
```

P.S.

да, через `choice` компактнее код

```
import random

text = [random.choice('abc123') for _ in range(10)]
text[5] = random.choice('ABC')

print(''.join(text))
```

или вообще так:

```
text = [random.choice('abc123') if i != 5 else random.choice('ABC') for i in range(10)]

print(''.join(text))
```

или так (еще на длине немного сэкономить) :) :

```
text = [random.choice('abc123' if i != 5 else 'ABC') for i in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
from random import choice
import string
all = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
five = string.ascii_uppercase
print(''.join(choice(all) for _ in range(5)) + choice(five) + ''.join(choice(all) for _ in range(6, 11)))
```

Answer (score 5):

Странно, что до сих пор никто не привёл самого Pythonic решения:

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, digits
from random import choice, choices

letters_and_digits = ascii_lowercase + digits

res = ''.join(choices(letters_and_digits, k=4))  # Сначала выбираем 4 любых буквы/цифры
res += choice(ascii_uppercase)  # Одну uppercase букву
res += ''.join(choices(letters_and_digits, k=5))  # Ещё 5 букв или цифр

print(res)
```

Answer (score 3):

Могу предложить что-то вроде такого:

```
from random import randint

def getRandStr(lenght):
    return "".join(chr(randint(33, 125)) for _ in range(lenght))


res = getRandStr(4) + chr(randint(65, 90)) + getRandStr(5)
print(res)
```

В принципе все просто:

- Функция `getRandStr(lenght)` генерирует случайные символы (на основе их `ascii` кодов, диапазон от *33* до *125* это латинские буквы, цифры, знаки препинания. Если не устраивает - можете задать свой)
- Далее случайный символ из диапазона *65* - *90* это только заглавные латинские буквы
- И еще случайная строка

---

[image: Таблица ascii кодов]